# How to get a substring with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

My program parses an XML-File which contains paths. Now I need to parse special folders like `Appdata` on different Windows devices:

```
<entry path="C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\myprogram" />
```

My attempt is to change the line into:

```
<entry path="#{APPDATA}\myprogram" />
```

and parse it using a Regular Expression:

```
string pattern = "#{ * }"; // what does fit here?
```

I've read some tutorials one Regex but I just can't figure out which Regex fits here.

How can I get the content between `#{` and `}` using a regular Expression?

Comment: Why do you need regexp? If you have map of special paths that you want to change, simply `string.Replace` would do the job

Comment: @IgorisAzanovas And i wouldn't do this with a string containing the whole XML. Use the XMLDocument - Object to get the entry and modify it's "path" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register general placeholders which you replace, e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, string> placeholders = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "#{APPDATA}", @"C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming" },
    { "#{SYSTEM32}", @"C:\Windows\System32" }
};

string ReplacePlaceholders (string text)
{
    foreach (var kv in placeholders)
    {
        text = text.Replace(kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Used like this:

```
// this would come from the XML attribute
string path = @"#{APPDATA}\myprogram";

string newPath = ReplacePlaceholders(path);
Console.WriteLine(newPath); // C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\myprogram
```

As for actual values paths, you can also use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) with the [`Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to get the actual paths. But for the replacements and also other values, the answer still applies

Finally, since I wasn’t sure from your question in what direction you wanted to make these replacements, of course you can also reverse the mapping in above dictionary. I just assumed you had placeholders you wanted to replace by real paths.

Comment: Environment.SpecialFolder?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a [match group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) in your regex. It would look like:

```
"#{(.*)}"
```

Then the Match.Groups property (documentation in the above link) would contain that "APPDATA" text.

---

This code prints "APPDATA" to the console

```
        var matches = Regex.Matches(@"#{APPDATA}\myprogram", "#{(.*)}");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
          Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: For the record, I think @poke has a better solution to the overall problem, but I went for an answer to the specific question of getting the text from a match in regex. If I was implementing this behavior I would use poke's solution.

Comment: @poke actually yes it is a valid regex. what is invalid about it? (unless you are talking about the surrounding quotes? The OP had it in a string assigned to a variable so I left the quotes in there)

Comment: Odd, I was thinking that the unescaped curly braces (a quantifier in regexes) would break but apparently, C#’s implementation is smart enough not to parse them as quantifiers when they don’t contain a number range. Nevermind me then :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question once again, maybe it is the other way you are asking?

```
void Main()
{
  string myXML = @"
  <x>
  <paths>
  <entry path=""#{APPDATA}\myprogram"" />
  <entry path=""#{APPDATA}\yourprogram"" />
  <entry path=""#{APPDATA}\hisprogram"" />
  <entry path=""C:\OtherFolder\DummyProgram"" />
  <entry src=""C:\OtherFolder\DummyProgram"" />
  </paths>
  <Other>Other</Other>
  </x>";

  var appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath( 
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData );
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);

  doc.Descendants("entry")
  .Where(xd => xd.Attribute("path") != null &&
      ((string)xd.Attribute("path")).StartsWith("#{APPDATA}"))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(e => {
     var oldPath = (string)e.Attribute("path");
     var newPath = Path.Combine(appdata, Path.GetFileName(oldPath));
     e.Attribute("path").SetValue(newPath);
     } );

  Console.WriteLine( doc.ToString() );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use Linq To XML for this. I couldn't see an exact pattern in your question, but probably something like this:

```
void Main()
{
  string myXML = @"
  <x>
  <paths>
  <entry path=""C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\myprogram"" />
  <entry path=""C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\yourprogram"" />
  <entry path=""C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\hisprogram"" />
  <entry path=""C:\OtherFolder\DummyProgram"" />
  <entry src=""C:\OtherFolder\DummyProgram"" />
  </paths>
  <Other>Other</Other>
  </x>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);

  doc.Descendants("entry")
  .Where(xd => xd.Attribute("path") != null &&
      ((string)xd.Attribute("path")).ToLower().Contains("appdata"))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(e => {
     var oldPath = (string)e.Attribute("path");
     var newPath = @"#{APPDATA}\" + Path.GetFileName(oldPath);
     e.Attribute("path").SetValue(newPath);
     } );

  Console.WriteLine( doc.ToString() );

}
```

Comment: What if my user name was appdata?

Comment: What does it matter? It would get replaced.

Comment: My point was mostly, that a path `C:\Users\appdata\Documents\foo\bar\baz` would be—incorreclty—replaced to `#{APPDATA}\baz` too.

Comment: I don't think it would be incorrect. I don't see in original question that states he already does know the path. He says if there is "appdata" in path. Maybe I should just make that \appdata\ instead of just appdata. It would be "correctly" replaced IMHO.